# Given a template and a controller instance in AngularJS, how can I compile the template in a way that it uses my controller instance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have a template and a controller instance. The template *does not* have an ng-controller directive on it. I want to compile the template in a way that it uses the controller instance that I supply. Here's the code I have so far:

```
var scope = $scope.$new();
var template = $templateCache.get('path/to/template.tpl.hml');
var controller = $controller('SomeController', {
    $scope: scope,
    foo: { ... },
    bar: { ... }
});
var html = $compile(template)(scope);

// Doesn't work correctly because the template has no controller.
scope.$apply();
```

**For those wondering why I want to do this in the first place**: I have a form that I pop open in a modal using the [ui-bootstrap $modal service](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). The arguments I pass to $modal are: a template URL, a controller name, and an object containing a bunch of data I want to inject into the controller (see linked docs for more). The $modal service takes care of instantiating the controller, injecting my data into it, compiling the template, and sticking all of this into a Bootstrap modal dialog. Since $modal has to inject things into the controller, the template cannot have an ng-controller attribute on it.

Popping up the modal works correctly in my app because $modal is doing its magic behind the scenes and somehow letting my template know what controller it is supposed to work with, but things aren't so rosy when I'm writing unit tests.

In my tests, I want to compile the template on my own using the $compile service. This gives me easy access to my form's scope and DOM tree. Of course, I'm unable to do this because I haven't been able to figure out what $modal is doing behind the scenes.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at [the source for ng-controller](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1fb47e08a0eed4d4ec4638367edb08dfbcce465b/src/ng/directive/ngController.js), you'll see that it is a very simple directive:

```
var ngControllerDirective = [function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: '@',
    priority: 500
  };
}];
```

So the magic in $modal is probably similar. Creating your own `ng-controller` for testing (or even for production) purposes is easy. Then in your tests you can use:

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
var template = '<div my-controller="ctrl1">{{x}}</div>'
html = $compile(template)($scope);
$scope.$apply();
```

Where `ctrl1` is just for testing. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nlFgQoi7Ys3uWS0sS2x6?p=preview) in action.

But that might be more than you need. In your tests, why don't you just add `ng-controller` at run time:

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
var template = '<div>{{x}}</div>'
html = $compile(template)($scope);
html.attr('ng-controller', 'ctrl1');
html = $compile(html)($scope);
$scope.$apply();
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GOeH680qYGyajxM9M8bK?p=preview) in action.